# Can I Install and use OLE DB for DB2 provider V 4.0 version 9.0.1356.0 on a Client Machine without installing Microsoft SQL Server 2012 or 2008 R2

Tags: vb.net, sql-server-2012, db2, oledb, provider

I develop a VB.Net application who use OLE DB Provider for DB2 to get and send data from/to distance DB2 database.
Do I have install  SQL Server 2012 or 2008 R2 and OLE DB Provider for DB2 for each client machine for an executable application VB.Net. **Is there any solution to avoid SQL Server 2008R2 or 2012 installation when I install the provider?**

[image]

If not **what is the necessary feature of SQL Server 2012 or 2008R2 to install and use DB2 V 4.0 version 9.0.1356.0?**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Why not use the OLEDB provider from IBM?

You don't say what platform and version of DB2, that will make a difference in where you find the appropriate driver from IBM.